# Using a Mailable instead of a MailMessage for password reset emails in Laravel 5.5

Tags: email, laravel-5, reset-password

I'd like my application to use Mailables for all of the emails it sends, so I created my own `ResetPasswordEmail` class that extends `Mailable`. Then I created my own `ResetPassword` notification class that extends the vendor class of the same name and overrode the `toMail` method as follows:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new ResetPasswordEmail())->with('token', $this->token);
}
```

Then I overrode the `sendPasswordResetNotification` from the `CanResetPassword` trait in my `User` model like this:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token));
}
```

Calling my custom `ResetPassword` notification class.

The problem is that if I use the default method of creating a `MailMessage` and sending it, it automatically populates the '**to**' field with the user's email. But when I use my `ResetPasswordEmail` mailable class, it doesn't.

Is there a good way to get it to work like that with my custom mailable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in the end I just set the "to" field for my Mailable instance like this:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new ResetPasswordEmail())->with('token', $this->token)->to($notifiable->email);
}
```

Since `$notifiable` is an instance of the `User` model in this case, I can get the email like that. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it works.